# How to find the time of an ec2 last used

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I need to make a list of all ec2 instances that I have with instanceid and last used time.
How can I make it?
Please advice.

Thanks.

Comment: You'll have to define "last used time."

Answer (score 0):

You will have to validate this with your use case, however I would imagine if the "Network In" and the "Network Out" metrics are 0 for some time the server is not being used as it is neither recieving nor sending out data.

The above mentioned metrics can be retrieved from Cloudwatch via its API.

Let me know if this helped.

Comment: Thanks.
@helloV: launchtime gives when the instance was created.

Answer (score 0):

Use [DescribeInstances](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ApiReference-cmd-DescribeInstances.html) to get the `instance_id` and `launch_time`

Do you want to use CLI or SDK?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows instances, you can use Windows Security logs.

More information here:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731826.aspx

You will have to perform some additional scripting in order to have this information in a central location but this solution will be 100% accurate.
You will be able to receive date/time, username and a lot of other important details.